# Connect a Google Spreadsheet for importing a FeatureCollection to Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet consisting a feature collection table. Is it possible to import the table in Google Earth Engine? I am a new learner of Earth Engine and was thinking that we have to upload a shapefile to the "Assets" and then import it to the code editor. So, can we just import it directly from a google spreadsheet using the url?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option at this time is these two steps:

1. Download from Google Sheets as CSV (*File → Download → Comma Separated Values (.csv)*).
2. Upload the CSV file to Google Earth Engine.

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable using the Python API, there is a workaround that you can use to do this. I highly suggest using Google Colab for the operation, since Earth Engine and geemap are easily connected to the notebook.

1. Read your Google Sheet into a Pandas DataFrame.
   The steps to do this have been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611729/getting-google-spreadsheet-csv-into-a-pandas-dataframe
2. Install geemap and use .pandas_to_ee() to convert your Pandas DataFrame to a ee.FeatureCollection.
   More information on how to do this can be found here:  https://geemap.org/notebooks/geopandas/